# can I recover a hard drive with a missing connecter?

Tags: hard-drive

I have this hard drive from (what i believe is) 2006. It is a SATA hard drive. so i can test it. but there is one problem about it.

The orange connecter piece that connects the main HDD disk and the HDD circuit board. is missing.

This causes the hard drive to not be seen by my computer. as it is physically not connected to the data disks.

So is there any way to recover this hard drive?

Comment: You would have to repair the HDD's connector, or pay somebody to transfer the platters to an identical model, before you could access the data.